# Shopify Pixel Extension - exit code 1

Tags: javascript, node.js, shopify, pixel

I wanted to create a web pixel extension for my shopify app, so I followed the instructions on the official shopify pixel extension creation guide: https://shopify.dev/apps/pixels/pixels-getting-started

When I'm trying to build the app, it outputs the following error:

```
extensions | my-app-pixel (C:\projects\shopify\my-app-pixel\node_modules\.bin\shopify-cli-extensions:2
extensions | basedir=$(dirname "$(echo "$0" | sed -e 's,\\,/,g')")
extensions | ^^^^^^^
extensions |
extensions | SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
extensions | at Object.compileFunction (node:vm:352:18)
extensions | at wrapSafe (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1033:15)
extensions | at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1069:27)
extensions | at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1159:10)
extensions | at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
extensions | at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
extensions | at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:77:12)
extensions | at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47)

━━━━━━ Error ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━
Command failed with exit code 1: C:/Users/user/AppData/Local/shopify-cli-nodejs/Cache/vendor/binaries/extensions/3.9.0-windows-amd64.exe build -
my-app-pixel (C:\projects\shopify\flaminjoy-galleries-pixel\node_modules\.bin\shopify-cli-extensions:2
basedir=$(dirname "$(echo "$0" | sed -e 's,\\,/,g')")
^^^^^^^

SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
at Object.compileFunction (node:vm:352:18)
at wrapSafe (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1033:15)
at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1069:27)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1159:10)
at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:77:12)
at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47)
```

Tried to create a blank app node template, run scaffold script but it didn't work, tried to change different terminals, cmd, powershell, I think the script is broken

**How to fix this line of script to work for Shopify?**
I just run build for shopify and it outputs the above error.

```
basedir=$(dirname "$(echo "$0" | sed -e 's,\\,/,g')")
```

Windows 10
Bash
Shopify CLI 3.9.0

Thanks,

Awaitin some responses/thoughts

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution: Shopify version @3.9.2 helped to solve this problem.

Comment: I guess you mean that you've upgraded to this version?

Comment: Yes, I've updated both cli and app packages to the 3.9.2 version